# about Fourier expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

A integrable function f(x) is an odd function ,f(x)$\geq$0 on (0,$\pi$)

Proof $|b_n|\leq nb_1$

$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

My attempt $b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

Let u=nx,then$b_n=\frac{\int_0^{n\pi} f(\frac{x}{n})\sin(x)dx}{n}$

Then I just need to proof $|\int_0^{n\pi} f(\frac{x}{n})\sin(x)dx|\leq b_1$

What should I do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove by induction that
$$
|\sin nx|\le n\sin x,
$$ for $0\le x\le \pi$.